# PHP exec - previous folder

Tags: php, web, cmd, exec

I want to run this part of PHP code.

```
$s=shell_exec("../sustav/zadatak/Generator_slika.exe ".$argumenti);
```

But I see that php doesn't run this command and didn't give me any error. So I wounder can I write ../ this in exec. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-notes):

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, **it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable**.

Comment: How to dis-activate safe mode?

Comment: @user1634243 Update to PHP version `5.4.0` or higher, or set `safe_mode` in `PHP.ini` to `0`

Comment: I try to set it to safe_mode = 0 , but that doesn't work. Can you give me other way to dis-activate safe mode?   PHP 5.3